# Is it a bad practice to use constants in switch case in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, switch-statement

In my React/Redux project I tend to use constants in switch case within **reducer**, since the name of each action tends to be long and complex, I'm wondering if it's a good practice?

```js
const ACTION_LIST = {
  add: 'ACTION_TYPE/ADD_CUSTOMER',
  remove: 'ACTION_TYPE/REMOVE_CUSTOMER',
  update: 'ACTION_TYPE/UPDATE_CUSTOMER',
};

const reducer = produce((draft, action: IQuickBarActions) => {
  const {type, payload} = action

  switch (type) {
    case ACTION_LIST.add: { // here
      // process the state
      break;
    }
    case ACTION_LIST.remove: {
      // process the state
      break;
    }
    case ACTION_LIST.update: {
      // process the state
      break;
    }
    default:
      // do something
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a perfectly fine practice — any time you have long string variables that you'll be using multiple times, throwing them in a variable is a good idea, since it'll allow your linter and autocomplete to help you out, and reduce typing. It's also very common with Redux actions, especially if you're exporting and using the same actions variables/object in other files (such as in a middleware, dispatch, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use constants but the way of using it is different for example:-

```
const ACTION_LIST = {
  add_list: 'ACTION_TYPE/ADD_CUSTOMER',
  remove_list: 'ACTION_TYPE/REMOVE_CUSTOMER',
  update_list: 'ACTION_TYPE/UPDATE_CUSTOMER',
};
```

because when you use the constant then you don't need to miss the spelling mistake and its more prominent to use also.